# Some pages are not loading in Sonarqube 5.6.6

Tags: sonarqube, devops, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

Suddenly I'm experiencing a huge problem in my Sonar. I cannot access some of the main pages under my projects.

For example, once I click on the project,

- home page not loading
- Measures page not loading
- Code page loading but once I click on any class, it's not opening and after a while, giving an error saying "Request cannot be processed. Try again later."
- List item

But if I do any analysis from Sonar-runner it's executing successfully. I don't see any other issues excepts things I pointed above.

I have taken following actions to rectify the issue but still no luck.

- Enabled debug logs to see any errors - cannot see any
- Did MySQL optimizations - still no luck
- Increased Sonar java heap size
- Installed another Sonarqube instance on another CentOS 7.4 fresh server and restored DB dump from old one. - still, the issue is same
- Finally, I have upgraded the new instance to Sonar 6.5. -but nothing changed and my issues still there.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QUHb.png)

Appreciate if somebody guides me to fix this issue. Since I cannot go for a fresh installation because I need all my History data.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried deleting the 'data/es' folder and restart the server?

Comment: Yes I already did this. still no luck.

Comment: if any one can help it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Anything interesting in your `logs/web.log`?

Comment: I don't see web.log under logs directory. I can see only access.log and sonar.log :(

Comment: What's [tag:devops] in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fixed this issue. I assumed this is something issue with the network response due to packet filtering or something else.

First I installed sonar in my local machine and then tried to execute Sonar-Runner analysis and then checked and it worked well.

Then I have realized this is something related to my remote network. therefore I have installed the Sonar in different location (Data center) and its also working.

Thanks to everyone for the guidance and I leave this post here so anyone can read later if they have the same issue.